# Google Apps Script to force open the document outline

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm sending a google doc (view only) out to a bunch of students. I would like the document outline to show by default. I know they can manually go in to the View menu and open the document outline, but is there any way to force open the document outline when students access the document (apps script?)